# Datetime picker and responsive Gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I am using this code to implement a DateTime picker and a responsive Gridview.

There is conflict between them.

The datetime picker stopped working when I added the responsive gridview 
how can i solve this conflict ?

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#<%= dtFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker();
  });
</script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/css/footable.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/js/footable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    ('#<%=grdMission.ClientID %>').footable({
      breakpoints: {
        phone: 300,
        tablet: 640
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Share the code for `GridView` and the `TextBox` as well.

Comment: order your library file properly.